# How to use VBA in EXCEL to perform stock back test

Tags: vba

How to use VBA in EXCEL to perform stock back test.

Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Provide some code of what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use InternetExplorer.Application object library to connect internet, please enable the library at VBA-->Tools->Reference, chose & tick "Microsoft Internt Controls". Creating round shape on  Excel sheet 1, click the sharp and chose "assign macro" that will add the following macro code, and you can run the code in auto after click the sharp   OR you can use "F5" key to run the code, and put all your stock numbers you want,&  put  & start it at  A6,A7,A8 ....etc..The macro will be finished the looping when Column A cell has no stocks number or empty.Please test the following code

VBA  Code

---

```
<code>
            Global myIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
            Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
            Public Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
            Sub Extract()
            Set myIE = Nothing
            Set myIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            'Set myIE = New InternetExplorer
            Dim a As String
            Dim b As String
            Dim g As Integer
            Dim workbookname As String
            Dim n As Integer
            Dim c As Integer
            Dim str As Variant
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            a = 4
            With myIE
             .Top = 10
            .Left = 1900
            .Height = 800
            .Width = 600
            .Visible = False
             Dim stockno As String
             Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
            .navigate "http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/eng/stocks/realtime/quote.php"
            Call WAITING(myIE, 10)
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").Select
             Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B6:Z1000").ClearContents
             Sleep (200)
            Do Until Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a + 2, 1) = ""
            stockno = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a + 2, 1)
            If stockno > 0 And stockno < 10 Then stockno = "0000" & stockno
            If stockno > 9 And stockno < 100 Then stockno = "000" & stockno
            If stockno > 99 And stockno < 1000 Then stockno = "00" & stockno
            If stockno > 999 And stockno < 10000 Then stockno = "0" & stockno
            b = 0
            Do Until b = 1
            On Error Resume Next
            .Document.all("quotesearch").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a + 2, 1)
            .Document.all("quotesearch_submit").Click
            b = InStr(myIE.Document.getElementById("StkQuoteHeader").innerText, stockno)
            Debug.Print b & "  " & stockno
            Sleep (1000)
            Loop
            n = .Document.getElementById("StkDetailMainBox").getElementsByTagName("span").Length
            Debug.Print n
            g = 0
            c = 0
            Do Until g > n - 1
             str = .Document.getElementById("StkDetailMainBox").getElementsByTagName("span").Item(g).innerHTML
            str = Replace(str, "&nbsp;", "")
            On Error GoTo Skip
            If Not Mid(str, 1, 1) = "" And Not Mid(str, 1, 1) = "B" And Not Mid(str, 1, 1) = "<" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(a + 2, c + 2) = str
            c = c + 1
            End If
            Skip:
            g = g + 1
            Loop
            a = a + 1
            Loop
            leave:
            myIE.Quit
            End With
            End Sub
            Function WAITING(ByRef myIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, ByRef state As Integer)
            Dim b As Variant
            With myIE
            b = Time()
            On Error GoTo L1
            Do Until Not .Busy And .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or TimeValue(Time()) - TimeValue(b) > TimeValue("00:00:15")
            Loop
                 If Not .Busy And .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE Then
                 DoEvents
                 state = 0
                 Else
                 state = 1
                 End If
               End With
            L1:
            End Function

</code>
```

Comment: Option:  Application.ScreenUpdating = False,  for faster code running speed,  .Visible = True, you can see the IE browser if you want